# How to replace the data of a matrix in an email with those in the text box of a userForm?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a UserForm with information and botton. When I click on "Demander Attest." (`cbAskAttestation`), which you can see here:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

this prepares me an email:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

However, how to replace the data in a matrix of an  email with those in the text box of a user form? I would like to replace the texts in the right column of the email table with the ones in the userform. For example, replace "GRADE" in the email with SAP.

## Annex

The data in the UserForm ufReservistInformations comes from this code:

```
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 2) = cboFunction
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 5) = cboSexReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 6) = cboRankReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 7) = txtIncorporationNumberReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 8) = txtBsnReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 9) = txtBirthdateReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 10) = txtAgeReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 11) = txtBirthplaceReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 12) = txtAddressReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 13) = txtZipcodeReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 15) = txtPhoneReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 17) = txtEmailReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 18) = txtContactReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 19) = txtJobReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 20) = txtEsrReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 21) = cboLengthContractReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 22) = txtEndEsrReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 23) = cboSav1Reservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 24) = txtSav1CommentReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 25) = txtRetrainingReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 26) = txtFmaChiefReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 27) = txtVsaReservist
        Sheets("RECAP").Cells(Lig, 28) = txtNextVsaReservist
```

And I create an email of the following template:

```
Sub CreateEmailfromTemplate(ByVal email As String, ByVal pathToTemplate As String)
    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    'Change the template file folder path according to your case
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(pathToTemplate)
    With NewMail
        .To = email
    End With
    NewMail.Display

    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

## Attempt with RobertBaron's answer described below

I tried to use Replace function.

```
Dim obApp As Object
Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set obApp = Outlook.Application
'Change the template file folder path according to your case
Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItemFromTemplate("\\bspp.fr\Travail\CCL1\MTMA\Groupe Adjudant de Compagnie\RESERVISTES\CORRESPONDANCE\Demande d'attestation de recyclage.msg")
With NewMail
    mailBody = .Body
End With

mailBody = Replace(mailBody, "1cl", cboRankReservist)
With NewMail
    .Body = mailBody
End With

NewMail.Display

Set obApp = Nothing
Set NewMail = Nothing
```

Yet the results don't keep the array and renders a column of words. Indeed here are the results just after using `mailBody = Replace(mailBody, "1cl", cboRankReservist)`

```
Bonjour,

J’ai l’honneur de vous demander une attestation de formation continue équipier-secouriste pour le personnel suivant : 


Groupement
1 GIS
Compagnie
20
N° incorporation
91109
Grade
1cl
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After this line has executed, `NewMail` contains a [MailItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem).

```
Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(pathToTemplate)
```

You can use the [Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.body) property to get the contents of the email as created by the template, change the contents, and set the Body property to the new contents. To set the values you want in the templated email, you can use the VBA [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/replace-function) function, to replace "Numero ?", "Grade ?", etc., by their desired values.

Comment: It's a good idea, however I'm not able to keep the array like format ...

Comment: Could you explain what the problem is?

Comment: In the debugger, what are the contents of Body before and after the Replace?

Comment: With `Debug.Print` ? I'm not use to it. I will try to do `Debug.Print Body` but I don't know where I get the information. Can I try to use a spy instead ?

Comment: Ah! You need to learn how to use the VBA debugger, set breakpoints, examine contents of variables, etc. This is a must for debugging programs. Just Google on it, you will find nice tutorials.

Comment: Just did and updated my question. I will sleep less idiot tonight! Bad news : `Replace` actually destroy the beautiful array I did in the email.

Comment: By putting breakpoints in your code, you will be able to examine the contents of Body and see why the Replace() function does not work. Are you saying that the Template has been changed?

Comment: Yes, `Replace` works very well but destroys the array I did in the template

Comment: Ok, then try to recover your Template .msg file, and next time, in VBA make a copy of the .msg file, and use the copy to create the email.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main ways for working with bodies in Outlook:

1. [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx).
2. [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx).
3. The Inspector class provides the [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns an instance of the Document class from the Word object model which represents the message body. Outlook uses Word as an email editor.

You can read more about that in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) article.

It is up to you which way is to choose. But I think Word may help in this scenario. To use these techniques in Outlook VBA code, use the Tools | References command to add a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library.